# du warning for netapp data ontap backend

Tags: du, netapp

I ran the following command
du --apparent-size --block-size=1 --summarize /mnt2/nfspools/_root_root_p1
PS: /mnt2/nfspools/_root_root_p1 is mount point for volume in data ontap filer.

I got the following output:

du: WARNING: Circular directory structure.
This almost certainly means that you have a corrupted file system.
NOTIFY YOUR SYSTEM MANAGER.
The following directory is part of the cycle:
  `/mnt2/nfspools/_root_root_p1/.snapshot/hourly.0'

du: WARNING: Circular directory structure.
This almost certainly means that you have a corrupted file system.
NOTIFY YOUR SYSTEM MANAGER.
The following directory is part of the cycle:
  `/mnt2/nfspools/_root_root_p1/.snapshot/nightly.0'

du: WARNING: Circular directory structure.
This almost certainly means that you have a corrupted file system.
NOTIFY YOUR SYSTEM MANAGER.
The following directory is part of the cycle:
  `/mnt2/nfspools/_root_root_p1/.snapshot/hourly.1'

du: WARNING: Circular directory structure.
This almost certainly means that you have a corrupted file system.
NOTIFY YOUR SYSTEM MANAGER.
The following directory is part of the cycle:
  `/mnt2/nfspools/_root_root_p1/.snapshot/hourly.2'

du: WARNING: Circular directory structure.
This almost certainly means that you have a corrupted file system.
NOTIFY YOUR SYSTEM MANAGER.
The following directory is part of the cycle:
  `/mnt2/nfspools/_root_root_p1/.snapshot/hourly.3'

16384   /mnt2/nfspools/_root_root_p1

is there any setting I can do netapp data ontap to avoid this warning when I run du command?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to avoid this warning message.

On filer volume I ran the following command:

```
vol options perf_test_pool2 nosnapdir on
```

The above command hides the .snapshot directory when accessing volume content.